# How to get an added value from multiple checkboxes in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes added with a button. I want to assign a value of 150 for each checkbox that is checked. Maybe my logic is wrong, but i cant get it working. Ideas?

```
function getValues() {

    var cost = 0;
    var isChecked = $('.isLab').prop('checked');

    $('.isLab').each(function () {
        if (isChecked == true) {
            cost = 150
        }
    });
    alert(cost);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(getValues);

function getValues() {
    alert( $('.isLab:checked').length * 150 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="isLab"/> Item 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="isLab"/> Item 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="isLab"/> Item 3<br/>
<button>Get values</button>
```

Comment: @ehuizar We tend to overthink sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Comments inline...

```
function getValues() {

    var cost = 0;

    $('.isLab').each(function (index, element) {
        if (element.checked == true) { // reference current checkbox
            cost += 150; // ADD to it!
        }
    });
    alert(cost);
}
```